# gcr.io/distroless/java:11 use base version from 11:.0.6 to 11.0.8

Tags: java, docker, jib, maven-jib, gcr.io

Changing minor version in distroless java docker image .

Current java project uses maven jib to build the docker images.
The default version of docker image is java 11. The minor java version of this docker image is set to 11.0.6.

How to change java minor version of this image gcr.io/distroless/java:11 from 11.0.6 to higher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Sep 11, 2020: `gcr.io/distroless/java:11` mirrors Debian 9 (stretch). Debian 9 is ["oldstable"](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianOldStable) that I believe only gets occasional important security updates. You should use the Debian 10 (buster)-based `gcr.io/distroless/java-debian10:11`, which gets the 11.0.8 Debian Java package.

In the near future, Distroless may advance the baseline by making `gcr.io/distroless/java:11` point to Debian 10, but as of now, it is pointing to Debian 9.

Comment: This answer really saved my day, thank you!! Do you have a source on these versioning details? I'm curious where you found this, since I couldn't find anything about this in the GCR documentation or code